# how to show buttons over viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-framelayout

I have viewpager in which each fragment has videoview now I want to show buttons over that view pager. I am using frame layout for that. but still not able to make those buttons visible overview pager. only fragments in my view pager are visible but the buttons which I want to show over viewpager pager are not getting visible.
 when activity starts at that time buttons are shown for 2.3 secs when as soon as video in fragment  become visible that buttons are not visible

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".Activities.MenuButtonActivity">


    <com.abp.app.ViewPager.NonSwipeableViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_bottom_overlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="yyyyyyyy"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_left_arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:text="yyyyyyyy" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_below_share"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:text="yyyyyyyy"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_right_arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="yyyyyyyy"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_left_arrow" />
    </RelativeLayout>




     </FrameLayout>
```

here is the code of acitivity

```
package com.abp.app.Activities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.abp.app.Adapter.MyPageAdapter;
import com.abp.app.CallerFuntionClasses.FunctionsCallApiFromServer;
import com.abp.app.Fragments.ConnectivityFragment;
import com.abp.app.Fragments.LondonRoyalDocksFragment;
import com.abp.app.Fragments.MasterPlanFragment;
import com.abp.app.Fragments.OfficesFragment;
import com.abp.app.Fragments.ProjectTeamFragment;
import com.abp.app.Fragments.VideosFragment;
import com.abp.app.R;
import com.abp.app.Utilities.AppVeriableClass;
import com.abp.app.Utilities.CustomSharePreferences;
import com.abp.app.Utilities.UtilsForDownloadDataFromServer;
import com.abp.app.ViewPager.NonSwipeableViewPager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.widget.RelativeLayout.ABOVE;

public class MenuButtonActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;
    private int BtnHeight = 0;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private TextView tv_progressCounting;
    private static String dirPath;
    boolean doubleBackToExit = false;
    FrameLayout frameLayout;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
    FunctionsCallApiFromServer apiFromServer;
    String accessTokenType,accessToken;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    CustomSharePreferences customSharePreferences = new CustomSharePreferences();
    ConnectivityManager conMgr;
    NetworkInfo netInfo;
    ArrayList<String> test;
    /////////////  Fragments //////////
    MasterPlanFragment masterPlanFragment ;
    OfficesFragment officesFragment;
    ConnectivityFragment connectivityFragment ;
    VideosFragment videosFragment ;
    LondonRoyalDocksFragment londonRoyalDocksFragment;
    ProjectTeamFragment projectTeamFragment ;

    MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;
    com.abp.app.ViewPager.NonSwipeableViewPager viewpager;

    ////////////////////////////////////
    private android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    private static final int[] menuBtnIdsArray = {R.id.btn_masterplan,R.id.btn_Offices,R.id.btn_connectivity,R.id.btn_londonroyaldock,R.id.btn_videos,R.id.btn_projectteam};

    private ArrayList<Button> menuBtnArrayList = new ArrayList<Button>();

    private int previousClickedButton = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_manu_buttons);
        viewpager = (com.abp.app.ViewPager.NonSwipeableViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewpager.setPagingEnabled(false);



        List fragments = getFragmetns();
        pageAdapter = new  MyPageAdapter( getSupportFragmentManager(),getFragmetns());
        viewpager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);


        VariableInitialize();
//        CallAPIFromServer();
        hideStatusBar();
       // onclickBtnFrangment();
       // firstTimeAlwaysCallFragment();
    }

    private void firstTimeAlwaysCallFragment() {
        frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        setFragment(masterPlanFragment);
        menuBtnArrayList.get(0).setBackgroundColor(menuBtnArrayList.get(0).getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.button_pressed));
    }

    private void VariableInitialize(){
        context = MenuButtonActivity.this;
        activity = MenuButtonActivity.this;

        ////////////// Fragment Initialize/////////////////
        masterPlanFragment = new MasterPlanFragment();
        officesFragment = new OfficesFragment();
        connectivityFragment = new ConnectivityFragment();
        londonRoyalDocksFragment = new LondonRoyalDocksFragment();
        videosFragment = new VideosFragment();
        projectTeamFragment = new ProjectTeamFragment();
        ////////////////////////////////
        conMgr =  (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        netInfo= conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        apiFromServer = new FunctionsCallApiFromServer();
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("AccessToken",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        accessToken = sharedPreferences.getString("Token",null);
        accessTokenType = sharedPreferences.getString("Type",null);
        dirPath = UtilsForDownloadDataFromServer.getRootDirPath(getApplicationContext());
       // frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainContainter_fragment);
        params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        //tv_progressCounting = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewProgressCount);
        //progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    }


    private void onclickBtnFrangment(){
        for (int i = 0; i< menuBtnIdsArray.length; i++){
            final int currentBtnSelected = i;
            menuBtnArrayList.add((Button)findViewById( menuBtnIdsArray[i]));
            try {
                menuBtnArrayList.get(currentBtnSelected).setText(AppVeriableClass.getInstance().menuDisplayNames.get(i));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            menuBtnArrayList.get(i).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch (menuBtnArrayList.get(currentBtnSelected).getId()) {
                        case R.id.btn_masterplan:
                            setFragment(masterPlanFragment);
                            frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                            selectedBtnColorChange(currentBtnSelected);

                            break;
                        case R.id.btn_Offices:
                            setFragment(officesFragment);
                            frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                            selectedBtnColorChange(currentBtnSelected);

                            break;

                        case R.id.btn_connectivity:
                            setFragment(connectivityFragment);
                            frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));// display full screen
                            selectedBtnColorChange(currentBtnSelected);

                            break;

                        case R.id.btn_londonroyaldock:
                            setFragment(londonRoyalDocksFragment);
                          //  params.addRule(ABOVE,R.id.linearlayout); // display show above on the menu bar as per the requirement.
                            frameLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
                            selectedBtnColorChange(currentBtnSelected);

                            break;
                        case R.id.btn_videos:
                            setFragment(videosFragment);
                           // params.addRule(ABOVE,R.id.linearlayout); // display show above on the menu bar as per the requirement.
                            frameLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
                            selectedBtnColorChange(currentBtnSelected);

                            break;
                        case R.id.btn_projectteam:
                            setFragment(projectTeamFragment);
                            frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                            selectedBtnColorChange(currentBtnSelected);

                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    // After click the menu button this function change the color of button until you press the other button.
    private void selectedBtnColorChange(int current) {
        menuBtnArrayList.get(previousClickedButton).setBackgroundColor(menuBtnArrayList.get(previousClickedButton).getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.button_default));
        menuBtnArrayList.get(previousClickedButton).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        menuBtnArrayList.get(current).setBackgroundColor(menuBtnArrayList.get(current).getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.button_pressed));
        if (BtnHeight == menuBtnArrayList.get(current).getHeight()){
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, BtnHeight);
            menuBtnArrayList.get(current).setLayoutParams(params);
        }
        else{
            BtnHeight = menuBtnArrayList.get(current).getHeight() + 10;
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, BtnHeight);
            menuBtnArrayList.get(current).setLayoutParams(params);
        }
        previousClickedButton = current;
    }

    private void hideStatusBar(){
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){

        if (doubleBackToExit){
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(context, "Click again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        this.doubleBackToExit = true;


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExit = false;
            }
        },2000);
    }

    private void CallAPIFromServer(){
        if (netInfo != null) {
            apiFromServer.getMediaResourceOffices(context, activity, accessTokenType, accessToken);
            apiFromServer.getMediaResourceConnectivity(context, accessTokenType, accessToken);
            apiFromServer.getMediaResourceLondonRoyalDock(context, accessTokenType, accessToken);
            apiFromServer.getMediaResouceVideo(context, accessTokenType, accessToken);
        }

    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        conMgr =  (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        netInfo= conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    }


    private void setFragment(Fragment fragment){
        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainContainter_fragment,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    private List<Fragment> getFragmetns()
    {
        List<Fragment> flist = new ArrayList<>();
        flist.add(MasterPlanFragment.NewIntance());
        flist.add(OfficesFragment.NewIntance());
        flist.add(ConnectivityFragment.NewIntance());
        flist.add(VideosFragment.NewIntance());
        flist.add(ProjectTeamFragment.NewIntance());


        return flist;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution.

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.MenuButtonActivity">

    <com.abp.app.ViewPager.NonSwipeableViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_bottom_overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:text="yyyyyyyy"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_left_arrow"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="yyyyyyyy"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_below_share"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="yyyyyyyy"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_right_arrow"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="yyyyyyyy"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And the result is.

[image]

Comment: your code is working fine in start it shows button at the bottom but as soon as the fragment is loaded in viewpager buttons again get invisible

Comment: @umair_aziz, can you please post the log that what happens when you load fragment. so I can figure out.

Comment: my logcat is that long that StackOverflow is saying you can't post more than 3000 words. what to do now ?? can I send it to you in email or through some other medium.

Comment: Upload the file or provide the link.

Comment: have u come across any solution for it?

Comment: Not able to download the file. Do one thing. debug your app and find out what is the cause.

Comment: here is the link from here u can download easily https://ufile.io/mzwc3 actually i tried a lot but not able to catch the problem that why need your bit help